# Extract variable values from ; separated string

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, string

My ASP.NET (VB.NET) application takes in a string of variables separated by a `;` character, like so: `q=castle;themes=3,4,11;price=1,450;`

What is the quickest way performance wise to extract a specific variable from this string, e.g. if I want to have the value of variable `themes` it would have to return the string `3,4,11`.

How can I do this? Maybe via a regular expression and if so which one? Or a custom function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively simple way of extracting a value from the string.

```
Dim str As String = "q=castle;themes=3,4,11;price=1,450;"
Dim themes As String = ""
For Each item As String In str.Split({";"c})
    Dim parts() As String = item.Split("="c)
    If parts.Length = 2 AndAlso parts(0).Trim = "themes" Then
        themes = parts(1).Trim
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with Dictionary and Linq

```
    Dim inputString As String = "q=castle;themes=3,4,11;price=1,450;"

    Dim resultDictionary = inputString.Split(";"C).ToList().Where(Function(x) x.Split("="C).Length > 1).[Select](Function(x) New With { _
    Key .x = x.Split("="C)(0), _
    Key .y = x.Split("="C)(1) _
}).ToDictionary(Function(key) key.x, Function(value) value.y)


    Dim themesValue = resultDictionary("themes")
```

Comment: This looks nice...how would I create a function for this? I tried `  Private Function getParameterValuesFromString(ByVal s As String) As Dictionary(Of )`, but not sure what to add a the dictionary type...
Also what do you reckon is faster, your code or @Blackwood's (see answer below)?